# Make input checkbox update when clicked, not when data is done

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, input

There is an input checkbox which can be clicked to be checked or unchecked:

```
<input
    type="checkbox" 
    ng-model="$ctrl.checkedOrNot"
    ng-change="$ctrl.doSomething()"
/>
```

---

```
doSomething() {
    this.MyService.setInput(this.checkedOrNot);
    if(this.loading) return;
    this.doStuff();
    this.doOtherStuff();
}
```

For the moment the check appears only after all the calls from `doSomething` are done. Is there a way to make it appear right when it's clicked?

Comment: what's going on in `setInput`? Probably this is because of two-way data binding

Comment: @Leo Messi have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using angular **1.3.x** or above you can use `ng-model-options` to limit the amount of `$digest` cycles by setting a `debounce` value up to `0`.

Take a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)